# Is totally disconnected space, Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Recall a space is totally disconnected if the only connected subsets are singletons (one-point subsets). Is a totally disconnected space,  Hausdorff?

> I think it is true since if $a $ and $b $ are two distinct points, they can be separated two disjoint  open sets, since the main space is totally disconnected (see Theorem at < http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/general-topology/totally-disconnected-space.html >).

Is this argument true?

Comment: As Eric Wofsey points out, there are two separate definitions of "totally disconnected." In the linked article, they are using a different definition than the one you began with.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X=\mathbb{N}\cup\{a,b\}$, where a subset of $X$ is open iff it either is contained in $\mathbb{N}$ or it contains all but finitely many points of $\mathbb{N}$.  Then $X$ is not Hausdorff (you can't separate $a$ and $b$).  However, it is totally disconnected: suppose $S\subseteq X$ contains more than one point.   If $S$ contains a point of $\mathbb{N}$, then that point is clopen and thus $S$ is disconnected.  The only other case is where $S=\{a,b\}$, but then $S$ is again disconnected because $\{a\}=S\cap (\mathbb{N}\cup\{a\})$ and $\{b\}=S\cap (\mathbb{N}\cup\{b\})$ are both open in $S$.

Comment: If we asume that  the main space is compact, is in this case the answer is false? Thank you Eric

Comment: In special case,  for a commutative ring with identity, when $Max (R) $ is totally disconnected,  can we deduce that it is Hausdorff?

Comment: The example $X$ in my answer is compact.  I don't know the answer to your second question off the top of my head; I suggest you ask it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric. < http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508168/is-max-r-a-hausdorff-space  >

Answer (score 0):

No. A totally disconnected space need not to be Hausdorff. Only T1 separation axiom is satisfied.