# Is Max (R) a Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Recall a space is totally disconnected if the only connected subsets are singletons (one-point subsets). Now let $R $ be a commutative ring with identity such that $\operatorname{Max}(R)$ is a totally disconnected space, in the sense of the Zariski topology.

I want to know if $\operatorname{Max}(R)$ Hausdorff in this case?

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222454/is-max-r-a-hausdorff-space